# MySql: Inser Into ... Select ... Where return #1054 error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with a column both containing the same data.

The first table is called "countries" and has the following structure:

```
ID -> primary key;
name_countries;
code_countries;
code_city;
name_city;
longitude_city;
latitude_city.
```

The second table is called "ar_geozone" and has the following structure:

```
country;
code_city;
name_city;
longitude;
latitude.
```

I would like to copy all data from "ar_geozone" to "countries", for those rows where there is a match between "ar_geozone.country" and "countries.code_countries".

But when I use this SQL string,

```
INSERT INTO countries (code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city) 
SELECT code_city, name_city, longitude, latitude FROM ar_geozone
WHERE ar_geozone.country LIKE countries.code_countries
```

the system returns the error: # 1054 - Unknown column 'countries.code_countries' in 'where clause'.

Comment: You need an update, not an insert if you want to update records.

Comment: I do not have to update, but insert because the tables "code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city" are empty.

Comment: As show in the accepted answer: update. That columns in your table are empty is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use an Update instead of Insert

From what I have understood, you already have code_countries populated in the table and you have to fill code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city columns.
Instead of insert try to use an update

- "*UPDATE countries ct SET code_city = (SELECT code_city FROM ar_geozone ag WHERE ag.country LIKE ct.code_countries)*"

Similarily you can write for other columns.

=======

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this... Correct If I am wrong

```
INSERT INTO countries (code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city) SELECT code_city, name_city, longitude, latitude FROM ar_geozone WHERE ar_geozone.country LIKE code_countries
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `join` or subquery:

```
INSERT INTO countries (code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city) 
    SELECT code_city, name_city, longitude, latitude
    FROM ar_geozone ag
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM countries c
                  WHERE ag.country LIKE c.code_countries
                 );
```

The `LIKE c.code_countries` is a bit suspicious.  Normally, you would just use `=` for the comparison.

Comment: The code includes the data in the "countries" table, appending them to the existing ones.

Comment: Also with "=" the "code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city" tables are not updated. The data is added at the end of those present. I forgot to mention that the "code_city, name_city, longitude_city, latitude_city" tables are empty.

Comment: @IdeaProject . . . Although an `update` might be what you are looking for, you specifically asked for inserting new records:  "I would like to copy all data from "ar_geozone" to "countries", for those rows where there is a match between "ar_geozone.country" and "countries.code_countries".".